# check if more than 7 days are selected using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, momentjs

how can i check if more than 7 days are selected on calendar. I want to disable one button on the basis of this condition.

`fromDate` and `toDate` are global states in which i am setting date from calendar. Little bit confuse now.

```
{moment(fromDate, toDate).format("yyyy-MM-DD") >
      moment().subtract(6, "days") ? (
        <li className="nav-item disabled">
          <a className="nav-link disabled">Hourly</a>
        </li>
      ) : (
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a
            className={`nav-link${
              selectedOption === "hourly" ? " active" : ""
            }`}
            onClick={() => updatedSwitchData("hourly")}
          >
            Hourly
          </a>
        </li>
      )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method to check difference between two days.

```
var diff = moment(toDate).diff(fromDate, 'days')
alert('difference :' + diff)

alert('is difference more than 7: ' + (diff > 7))
```

Comment: condition not working.... its is giving value in minus

Comment: `var diff = moment(toDate).diff(fromDate, 'days')`

Comment: Or check `Math.abs(diff) > 7`.